# Peoplesoft - terminate appengine with custom cancel button

Tags: peoplesoft

I have created a custom cancel button which would terminate/kill an epic engine through peoplecode upon click.
In code I am updating tables PSPRCSRQST and PSPRCSQUE.
The code working fine for app engines in processing status, but if a process was in 'blocked status', then on clicking the button changes its status to 'cancel', but then it  starts processing after sometime.
Can you pls suggest why it is behaving this way for 'blocked' processes?

Comment: Check if 'Restart Enabled' is checked in the process definition.